# Context.io, Response object has protected properties

Tags: php, oop

I am working with context.io. I am able to get a response using the php api, however, the response is an object and contains protected properties.

Response is like this :

```
ContextIOResponse Object
(
[headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [request] => 
        [response] => 
    )
)
```

All i get is this response object from the server and i need to save those fields in Db.

Hopefully someone can give an idea

Comment: Have you tried looking up the class specs and see what methods are available?

Comment: What endpoint are you using? Does "using the php api" mean you're using the php library from here (https://github.com/contextio/PHP-ContextIO)? What methods are you calling? Can you include some example code?